# Java INSERT syntax error

Tags: java, ms-access

May i know what is the error in this sql statement, i use this method to add a schedule from my client. Im using RMI Technology

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+path+".accdb;";
        dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        ps = dbConn.prepareStatement("INSERT into Schedule(Subject, Student, Instructor, Time, Days, Room) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, subject);
        ps.setString(2, student);
        ps.setString(3, instructor);
        ps.setString(4, time);
        ps.setString(5, days);
        ps.setString(6, room);
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

an error always occur when i exposed this method, here it is  :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

Comment: the path there in "String database" is the path where my database is located

Comment: I presume there isn't a more detailed error message?

Comment: Which Access version are you using?

Comment: i guess time is not formatted in an acceptable way for the datatype

Answer (score 5):

Without a detailed error message, I can't be sure, but it could be because `Time` is a [reserved word in SQL for Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335).

Answer (score 0):

Its because of `Time is reserved keyword`.

Don't use **Time or From** which are common which developer used as table attribute that why they gets error `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement`

In your case so Instead of `Time` as attribute of table use any other name.

See this [Document which are Reserved Keywords.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The question is about Microsoft Access, not SQL Server.

Comment: @rgettman I just gave the example. its for almost for all database